# Not able to convert gRPC class object response to json

Tags: python, json, grpc

Response from API -

```
Main_Group {
  ID: 1
  Type: "Type1"
  Name: "S1"
  GUID: "HGDBJHIHL"
  eGUID: "d12b987c-eb2c-445c-a713-b70506f18116"
  dateOfSubmission {
    seconds: 1575237813000
  }
  startTimeStamp {
    nanos: 491854
  }
  endTimeStamp {
    nanos: 491854
  }
  startNano: 491854
  endNano: 491854
  version: 1
  TimeStamp {
    seconds: 1594141662000
  }
  Description: "Description 2"
  Source: "DB"
  score: 1
  State: PASS
}
```

using MessageToJson(response) is giving an error -

```
self = seconds: 1575237813000


    def ToJsonString(self):
      """Converts Timestamp to RFC 3339 date string format.
    
      Returns:
        A string converted from timestamp. The string is always Z-normalized
        and uses 3, 6 or 9 fractional digits as required to represent the
        exact time. Example of the return format: '1972-01-01T10:00:20.021Z'
      """
      nanos = self.nanos % _NANOS_PER_SECOND
      total_sec = self.seconds + (self.nanos - nanos) // _NANOS_PER_SECOND
      seconds = total_sec % _SECONDS_PER_DAY
      days = (total_sec - seconds) // _SECONDS_PER_DAY
>     dt = datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(days, seconds)
E     OverflowError: date value out of range
```

could anyone please suggest a way to convert the response to json ?

I tried -

```
js = str(response)
print(js)
js_pick = jsonpickle.encode(js, unpicklable=False)
print(json.dumps(js_pick))
```

but it is not giving what i need... please help if there is a pythonic way to do it.

Comment: I think your TimeStamps are in milliseconds (1575237813000) not seconds (1575237813). See: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#timestamp

Comment: yes @DazWilkin the time stamp is in Nanos and I just want it to be like "1575237813000" that's it... and nothing seems to be working.. could you please suggest if you have some experience dealing with timestamps?